# Install individual homebrew packages in different locations

Tags: applications, install, homebrew

to organize my applications folder a bit, I want to create subfolders in `/Users/username/Applications`, e.g. `/Users/username/Applications/Tools`.

Now programs installed via `brew` are automatically installed in the "main" applications directory and when manually moving them, brew throws an error on updating them as it can't encounter the previously installed app anymore:

```
Purging files for version 1.2.3 of Cask my-awesome-app
Error: my-awesome-app: It seems the App source '/Applications/my-awesome.app' is not there.
```

Is there a way to tell brew to either install the app directly in a specific directory or point it to where the app was moved after its initial install?